# RSS-reader that keeps unread items

Tags: windows-phone-7

So I have a simple RSS-reader, that has a feed that gets updated when the app is started. How can I add functionality that keeps the new unread items in a different color? I would like to make it visible for the user which posts are new since last time he/she opened the app.

Comment: Comes down to two things: Showing items in different colors and remembering what was read. A more specific question would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming you have a model something like;

```
public class RSSItem {
  public bool IsUnread { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

You'll want to bind the `ForegroundColor` of a `TextBlock` to your `IsUnread` property using a `IValueConverter` that takes a `bool` and returns a `Color`. So your XAML might look like;

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
  <converters:UnreadForegroundConverter x:Key="UnreadForegroundConverter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="RSSItems">
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{Binding IsUnread, Converter={StaticResource UnreadForegroundConverter}}" />
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Don't forget to add the `xmlns:converters` attribute to your Page's tag.

You'll then want to implement your `IValueConverter` to do the boolean to colour conversion;

```
public class UnreadForegroundConverter : IValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    if ((bool)value == true) {
      return Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
    }

    return Application.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"];
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

}
```

And obviously you'll need to bind the listbox, `RSSItems`, to a collection of `RSSItem`. Eg.

```
ObservableCollection<RSSItem> items = new ObservableCollection<RSSItem>();
// populate items somehow
RSSItems.ItemsSource = items;
```

Hope that helps.